# Mapbox not loading streets and details: Failed to load mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-streets-v6

Tags: ios, swift, maps, mapbox

Just installed `MapboxGL` through cocoapods. 
I initialize it in my `ViewController` like the example given:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var mapViewWrapper: UIView!

    var mapView: MGLMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Map
        let styleURL = NSURL(string: "asset://styles/dark-v7.json")
        mapView = MGLMapView(frame: mapViewWrapper.bounds, styleURL: styleURL)
        mapView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleHeight

        // set the map's center coordinate
        mapView.setCenterCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.894368,
            longitude: -77.036487),
            zoomLevel: 15, animated: false)
        mapViewWrapper.addSubview(mapView)

    }
```

When I launch the app, I see a black square and a Mapbox logo but no streets, see image below
[image]

In the logs I'm getting this:

```
[ERROR] {Map}[Style]: Failed to load [mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-streets-v6]: 
[ERROR] {Map}[Style]: Failed to load [mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2]:
```

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: I changed the target name and refreshed the schemes and it worked but not sure what happened.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this [on GitHub](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/2012), much appreciated. To close the loop here, this problem happened because the Mapbox iOS SDK was inappropriately caching requests made with bad access tokens, which tended to give vague errors that looked like connection issues.

Fixed in v3.1 by [this](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/pull/3479).

Answer (score 0):

This may have been an intermittent network or API problem? The usage looks right.